# pgf file overlap in labels of bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to import a bar chart I created using python and Matplotlib into my LaTeX document. However when I save the chart as a pgf file and import it into my document there is always a slight overlap between my labels and the actual chart so it looks like some text is cut off. I have tried changing parameters in my python program (like adding whitespace to all the labels when generating the graph) but I always get the same pgf so the issue is on the LaTeX side. You can see the problem here:

The original graph from matplotlib:
[image]

And the pgf file (screenshot of the generated pdf):
(Removed because I need atleast 10 reputation to post more than 2 links)

If you look carefully at the screenshot you can see the overlap.

I am adding the pgf file to my document using the code:

```
\centerline{\scalebox{0.5}{\input{meat.pgf}}}
```

Also as an aside, my imported pgf file only occupies 2/3 of the page, is there any way to stretch the graph downwards so it fills the whole page?

If anyone knows how to fix this it will be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is a minimum working example, it is not my whole document but it compiles and produces the problem, I have tried applying the san-serif fix and although the overlap is reduced it still exists:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath,booktabs,csvsimple,pdfpages,graphicx,pgf}  
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Minimum Working Example}
\date{}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Meat Dishes}

\section{Overall}
\newpage
\centerline{\scalebox{0.5}{\sffamily\input{meat.pgf}}}

\end{document}
```

And here is the screenshot when I use a san-serif font (notice the overlap on the Chicken, Bacon and Mozzarella Pasta Bake):
Removed due to needing reputation for more than 2 links.

And here is the pgf file needed to compile (just put it in the same directory as the tex file of the MWE):
[meat.pgf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1IzwxXN_Fh2eDlCR29CWGxJRUk)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Without any code I can only guess: the original uses a sans serif font (what you get with `\textsf{...}`) for the labels and your document a serif font. I guess that in the .pgf file the labels are left alinged at a position far enough left to appear right allignt. And this doen't work properly anymore with a different font. Try `\centerline{\scalebox{0.5}{\sffamily\input{meat.pgf}}}`. Does the overlap change?

Comment: @Bobyandbob  I have added a MWE to the question.

Comment: @Mike I changed to a san-serif font which improved the graph somewhat but there is still some overlap.

Comment: Your MWE is useless, we cant compile it. it seems that you have problem in `meat.pgf`, which is not known. There you have wrong positioned text on the left side of graph. also use of `scalebox` and `centerline` is fragile

Comment: @Zarko Oops, I forgot to put up 'meat.pgf' . I'll add it in to my question so you can download it and compile the document with that.

Comment: For us is simpler, if you integrate this file in your MWE, i.e. don't use `\input{...}˙but in this place put content of `meat` file. Help us to help you. Most of us haven't time for downloading and compose your MWE or simple not willing to do this.

Comment: @Zarko Right, I have done that now.

Comment: Well, my guess was correct. Two lines from meat.pgf (shortened): `\pgftext[x=3.192681in,y=8.659097in,left,base] ...`, `\pgftext[x=3.500949in,y=8.934211in,left,base] ...`. The text is left aligned and positioned to make it appear right aligned. Your should try to make Mathplotlib use propper alignment and positioning or, as a workaround, make it use the same font you want to use in your document. But since I don't know Mathplotlib, I can't help you with that. It would be off topic here anyway.